# Java array.length method

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting error: Undefined symbol:length.

```
import java.util.*;

class ssss

{

  public static void main(String args[])

    {

     int a[]={1,2,3,4};
     System.out.println(a[1]);
     int x = a.length();  
     System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting error:  Undefined symbol:length.

Comment: `length()` is not a method its a field of an array.

Comment: In your question, all your code should be formatted as code, and you should explicitly say what the question is rather than posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

`length` is a field for arrays and not a method. Use `a.length`

Answer (score 1):

@TheLostMind answer

change

```
 int x = a.length();
```

to

```
int x = a.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

length() is not a valid method. So you can try like this

```
class ssss
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a[]={1,2,3,4};
        System.out.println(a[1]);
        int x = a.length;  
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

length is a public attribute not a method in array. Therefore, we access the length of array as :

```
int x = a.length;
```

and not as,

```
int x = a.length();
```